# How to use external library not available in NPM or bower in react/webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I see this library here:

http://sztanko.github.io/crosslet/

There is no bower install, there is no npm install, but I want to use it in my webpack reactjs ES6 app. How can I do this properly? If not possible with ES6, JSX is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Include the library as an `external` in your webpack configuration as [described in the Webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

You can then refer to it as a normal import in your code, and when it's webpacked, it creates import shims that expect to find the global.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @BrandanMolloy said, you can also just include it as an asset (js/css) within your project and utilize the libraries. If you explore the examples within http://sztanko.github.io/crosslet/ you'll see a bunch of uses, eg

`new crosslet.MapView($("#map"),config);`

here https://github.com/sztanko/crosslet/blob/gh-pages/examples/happiness/index.html